# Decompile apk but has bug in xml file

Tags: android, xml, decompiler

I'm newbie to Android and reverse engineering.I'm now trying to decompile an apk file and import it in Android Studio and run it.I use BBCnews as my apk file and use an online decompile site : `www.javadecompilers.com/apk` ,I get an zip file and when I import the folder into Android Studio,
it comes that there exists some error in the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://paste.ofcode.org/GD6giZeb7yx2JprmizHYgp).

First I change `xmlns:` in the third line to `xmlns:android=`,but there still exists many errors.For example,in 11th line,at `android:name="bbc.mobile.news.app.ww.BBCNewsWwApp"`,comes three error:

1. Unresolved package 'app'
2. Unresolved package 'ww'
3. Unresolved class 'BBCNewsWwApp'

and many other similar errors in the file. 
My file structure is shown in:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpHy0.jpg).There does exist an class 'BBCNewsWwApp',and the defination of this class:

```
package bbc.mobile.news.app.ww;

import bbc.mobile.app.NewsApplication;
import bbc.mobile.news.ww.receiver.AlarmReceiverWw;

public class BBCNewsWwApp extends NewsApplication {
    private static final String TAG = "BBCNewsUkApp";

    public Class<?> getAlarmReceiverClass() {
        return AlarmReceiverWw.class;
    }
}
```

I think decompiling should be accurate and I'm very confused why there exist so many errors?

Comment: can you add your build.gradle files

Comment: It seems that the output of decompiling doesn't have a build.gradle file,Android Studio even ask me to transform my project to a gradle project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every APK that are released on Play Store or somewhere else has shrinked it's `code` and `resources` using **progaurd**.

Earlier It was possible to reverse engineer an apk when Android development was done on `Eclipse`. After Google introduced **Android Studio**, by default it is obfuscate apk using default progaurd files.

So You will not able to fully reverse engineer an APK.

For more information check [obfuscation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html).

Comment: Thank you very much.So does it mean that if I want to add some function to an existing app,the only way is understanding the decompiled code and develop a new one from scratch?

Comment: @norshtein tooma Yes!